# File upload and progess bar

Tags: java, javascript, web, dojo

I want to display progress bar depending upon amout of file read when we upload the file.

How can we achive this using JS and Servlet I know for upload I can use apache commons lib but how will display progess bar depending upon data read.

Should I send countious response to JS code depending upon amount of data read if so how can this be achived? OR any one knows of better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my Application to dynamicly add a progressbar to a table, i did cut of a bunch of code, so there might be missing something. you can simply call a `post` to a server with this in the `set_percantage` method.

Sorry if there is still some german language written in there, or if there are one or two statemants to much in there, in original this are like 400 lines, filling a large table.

EDIT: i am getting the information by an `applet` in this, there you can simply write a `post` to your server

```
function addDownload(filename, datPfad) { 


  var table       = document.getElementById("download_table");
  var body        = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

  var progres     = function() {

  var getVars                     = this;    
  this.file                       = filename;

  this.tr                         = document.createElement("tr");

  this.td3                        = document.createElement("td");

  this.progress                   = document.createElement('div');
  this.container                  = document.createElement("div");
  this.progressbar                = document.createElement("div");
  this.bar                        = document.createElement("div");
  this.text                       = document.createElement("div");
  this.path                       = datPfad;

  this.progressbar.style.width     = "100%";
  this.progressbar.style.height    = "20px";
  this.text.style.fontSize         = "10px";

  this.bar.className               = "progress";

  this.progressbar.appendChild(this.bar);


  this.text.style.marginTop        = "-19px"
  this.text.style.textAlign        = "center";
  this.text.style.textSize         = "15px";


  this.text.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Download starting"));
  this.progressbar.appendChild(this.text);

  this.container.appendChild(this.progressbar);

  this.td3.appendChild(this.container);

  this.td3.setAttribute("width", "32%");

  this.tr.appendChild(this.td3);

  this.tr.setAttribute("style", "background:rgb(245, 245, 245)");

  this.tr.setAttribute("id",filename);

  body.appendChild(this.tr);

  this.set_percantage = function() {
          progress                = document.jsap.getProgress(getVars.file);
          this.bar.style.width    = progress + "%";
          downloaded              = document.jsap.getDownloadedSize(getVars.file);
          filesize                = document.jsap.getDownloadSize(getVars.file);
          this.text.removeChild(this.text.firstChild);
          textnode = (downloaded == 0.0 || filesize == -1.0) ? "Download starting" : downloaded + " MB of " + filesize + " MB downloaded";
          this.text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textnode));
          if(downloaded >= filesize && downloaded != 0) {
              row.beendet();
          }


  }

  this.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
      if(boxbuffer.innerHTML == "finished") {
          window.clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
      row.set_percantage();
  },2000);

}
```

and i forgot the css class in here:

```
.progress {
            width:0%;
            height:100%;
           background: rgb(30,205,230); /* Old browsers */
            /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(38deg, rgba(30,205,230,1) 0%, rgba(90,156,250,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,205,230,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(90,156,250,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(38deg, rgba(30,205,230,1) 0%,rgba(90,156,250,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(38deg, rgba(30,205,230,1) 0%,rgba(90,156,250,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(38deg, rgba(30,205,230,1) 0%,rgba(90,156,250,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(38deg, rgba(30,205,230,1) 0%,rgba(90,156,250,1) 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1ecde6', endColorstr='#5a9cfa',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
            z-index:2;
            }
```

so, what i am basicly doing is, i creating an div elemnt with the width of 0%. 
The xml returns me the procentual of the downloaded file. Based on this number, i am increasing the width of the div element.

Comment: BUt lets say i have multiple file uploading and i have to show as many no of progress bars as file are there what is the logic i should using

Comment: Can i dynamically genrate "<div data-dojo-type="dijit/ProgressBar" style="width:300px" data-dojo-id="myProgressBar" id="downloadProgress" ></div>" this div for   each file

Comment: and also i am using <input name="uploadedfile" multiple="true" type="file" id="uploader" dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Files">   is there way i can send one file at a time